# Set env based on query string using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to set an Env variable in htaccess using rewrite based on the query string. I want to set ENVIRONMENT to mobile if mobile=true in the query string

So far I have tried a few things but am stuck with this rule which I think should work but sadly is not working...

```
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^mobile=true$
   RewriteRule .* - [E=ENVIRONMENT:mobile]
```

Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a small typo in the form of a `!` that is preventing you from getting the result you're after.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mobile=true$
RewriteRule .* - [E=ENVIRONMENT:mobile]
```